# Scoping of a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, lifetime-scoping

Consider the following code:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) { /* do awesome stuff. 10 times! */ }

console.log(x);
```

`x` is still printed in the console.

This gives me warnings in JSHint, because a couple of lines further I do another loop, redeclaring `x`:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) { /* more awesome stuff */ }
```

Now I know that JSHint is not the holy grail, but is there a way to prevent `x` from leaking? (assuming that's the correct terminology?

I tried:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) { /* do awesome stuff. 10 times! */ }

    console.log(x);

    for (var x /* warning here */ = 0; x < 10; x++) { /* more awesome stuff */ }
})();
```

So `"use strict";` is not the way to go.

I tried scoping it even deeper (and this confuses me as much as that it makes me feel sick):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    {
        for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) { /* do awesome stuff. 10 times! */ }
    }

    console.log(x); // STILL WORKS...

    for (var x /* warning here */ = 0; x < 10; x++) { /* more awesome stuff */ }
})();
```

And even worse:

On the line with the `console.log` invocation JSHint warns me about `x` being used out of scope AND the next line that I'm redeclaring  `x`.

Comment: javascript is not block scoped, it's function scoped. Any variable declared in a function can be seen anywhere in that function.

Comment: I've seen `let` be used in a for loop instead of `var`.  But, honestly, I'd ignore JSHint.

Comment: All `var` declarations in a function are treated as if they occurred at the start of the function. There's no scoping but function scope. @bozdoz `let` is a JavaScript v. 6 feature and it's not universally supported.

Comment: See [Variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Answer (score 0):

Variables are *only* scoped to functions in JavaScript, not blocks. If you absolutely needed to scope each for loop separately, you would need to do something like this:

```
(function () {
    for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) { /* do awesome stuff. 10 times! */ }
})();
(function () {
    for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) { /* more awesome stuff */ }
})();
```

Or, you could just reuse the `x` variable without redeclaring it, which would still work fine.

Comment: In general it's considered good practice to declare all your variables up front, in this case just `var x;` at the start of the function. That way, you don't have to track down inline `var`s.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I find that useful for working out if my function needs to be refactored - too many variables might mean that some functionality can be moved to its own function.